# Does Superman ever make a reference to the New Year?

Tags: dc, superman

Does Superman ever make a reference to the New Year?

I've heard he has done so with Batman. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorta-on-topic: http://comiccoverage.typepad.com/comic_coverage/2007/12/supermans-new-y.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He attended at least one New Year's party ([src](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_%28Clark_Kent%29))

> On New Year's Eve 1999, Lex Luthor plans a spectacular party in Metropolis to usher in the New Year. Clark, Lois, and the Kents all attend.

Answer (score 2):

Action Comics #81 (1944) makes a very clear reference to New Year.

[image]

[image]

Clark attends a New Year's party in Superman #474 (1991)

[image]